# Groovy value is not apending in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
artifactVersion = getVersion('build.gradle')

println artifactVersion[enter image description here][1]

def getVersion(String fileName) {
      readFile(env.WORKSPACE+"/"+fileName).split("\n").each { line ->
          if ((line =~ /version (.*)/).count > 0) {
            echo line
            def m = (line =~ /version (.*)/)[0]
            echo m[1].replaceAll('"','').toString()
            println m[1].replaceAll('-SNAPSHOT','').toString()
            return m[1].replaceAll('-SNAPSHOT','').toString()
            }
      }
}
```

from getVersion api am getting the version 1.0 and that am attached in the console
but that 1.0 is not appending to the artifactVersion

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your code is that the return in getVersion does not return out of the function.

The curly braces in `list.each{  }` create an anonymous function. Calling return inside will only return from the current iteration of the each function. A normal for loop or a combination of find/findAll and collect (map in other languages) would be better.

See also [Groovy Closures](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) and [list methods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_manipulating_lists).

Comment: I didn’t get exactly so what should I do know

Comment: you cannot return from each block, use a normal for loop instead